# Tecnam twin p2006t electrical master switch when towing

Tags: towing

Does anyone know why the electrical master switch must be on before towing the p2006t? Seems odd to me; there is a reason, I just can't find it. Who knows this answer? Peter.

Comment: https://www.avsim.com/forums/topic/637865-tecnam-p2006t/

Comment: Presumably, you want to have the rotating beacon (or equivalent red top/bottom strobe) on while the aircraft is moving, whether while being towed or moving under its own power. There may be other reasons specific to this particular aircraft, but as a first thought, if not quite a definitive answer, I'll suggest that. Does the checklist that has you turn on the master switch specify other steps that would need electric power?